# How can I fetch data from my local database and sterilize to XML format?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core. I want to know is it possible to fetch and sterilize data from MSSQL database to an XML file using c#  or any other method? I am using Microsoft SQL Server 15.0.2080.9 and .net 5.0 in visual studio

[image: Sql Database Diagram]

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a **language** used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what concrete database system (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: i see, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Could you please specify what you want to export . I mean data or schema.

Comment: @DeepakKoshy i want to export data

Comment: Hi,  where did you want to export this file? wwwroot or local PC? Or you just want to serialize the data to xml format and display it in browser?

Comment: @Rena i would like to serialize the data to xml format then export it to my local pc. Is it make sense?

Comment: Hi, of course it make sense. I will show you a simple demo below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple demo about how to dowload xml file from database:

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
    //get the data you want from the database
    Test po = _context.Test.Include(a=>a.Items).ToList();
        
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    //serialize to xml
    serializer.Serialize(stream, po);

    //download the xml file
    return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/xml", "test.xml");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific if you're using MSSQL and MS SQL server then you can use it's export feature for data. I think here you're asking for your schema structure to convert it to XML is that right?

Sample code for Exporting data from table.

```
SELECT SalesRegion.SalesTerritoryRegion as Region,
    SUM(InternateSales.SalesAmount)  as SalesAmount
    FROM dbo.FactInternetSales  InternateSales

LEFT JOIN dbo.DimSalesTerritory SalesRegion
ON InternateSales.SalesTerritoryKey = SalesRegion.SalesTerritoryKey

GROUP BY SalesRegion.SalesTerritoryRegion

FOR XML AUTO,TYPE, ELEMENTS ,ROOT('RegionSales')
```

Answer (score 0):

To easily export data in Json or XML format please use  Azure data studio.
It is  a free toll . Install it , connect to local or cloud DB , write your sql query in  Query editor and export to different formats . Data studio currently supports json , xml ,csv and excel formats. I think it is ideal for exporting small volumes of data for analysis.

[image]

Thank you .